# React.Children.map vs React Children.toArray.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React `children` is the opaque data structure used in composition. To manapulate it, React exposes the `React.Children` API, which among others, contains the methods `React.Children.map` and `React.Children.toArray`.

According to the docs, `Children.map` invokes a function on every child element (usually to render, or `cloneElement`), while `toArray` changes from from the opaque `children` to a simple js array.

`React.Children.map(child, fn)` and `React.Children.toArray.map(child, fn)` feel effectively equivalent. I frequently see `Children.map` used, and was looking for solid evidence to backup the best practice, or an explanation for the use case of `toArray.map`.

My first instinct is that `toArray` obviously adds another call, which is potentially less performant (marginally?), but I believe `toArray` also strips out `undefined` or `null` children.

Answer (score 11):

It is a very old question, but i'm adding what i found out!

`Children.toArray` is a bit different with `Children.map` when passing `null` or `undefined` as children.

```
<ReactComponent>
  <div>one</div>
  { null }
</ReactComponent>
```

In the above example,

`Children.toArray` skips `null` or `undefined` and `length` of result will be `1`

however `Children.map(children, (val) => {})` also iterates when null, `length` of result will be `2`

Answer (score 7):

This difference between `React.Children.map` and `React.Children.toArray.map` is quite important if you are using [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Let's say you have this React Component

```
const ReactComponent = () => {
    return (
        React.Children.map((child, index) => (
            <div>{child}</div>
        ))
    )
}

const checkBooleanValue() => {
    return false;
}
```

You use it with a child and a conditional If:

```
<ReactComponent>
        <span>Child</span>
        {checkBooleanValue() &&
            <span>Another Child</span>
        }
</ReactComponent>
```

If `checkBooleanValue()` is `false`

- `React.Children.map` will give you two children

  - The `<span>` `React.Element`
  - `false` for the Inline If
- `React.Children.toArray.map` will give you just one child:

  - The `<span>` `React.Element`

With `React.Children.map` you'll therefore end up with an empty div for the 2nd child.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the react code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b1b4a2fb252f26fe10d29ba60d85ff89a85ff3ec/src/isomorphic/children/ReactChildren.js), `Children.toArray` is the same as `Children.map` passing the identity function `(x) => x`. Therefore `Children.map(children, func)` will be always more performant than calling `Children.toArray(children).map(func)`.